# Load template from different application in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJS application which need to load a pop-up modal which is present in some different application.

Is there a way to achieve it?

How can we load a template/modal which is not at all present in our application??

Comment: The different application you are talking about might have a URL right? If so, load it via a simple `HTTP get`  call.

Comment: yes. it has a different URL. I need to load it on any click event from my application. The catch is, it would be a form whose data I need to pass on to backend on submit

Comment: That should not be a problem, right? Your logic for form submission also be present in the same url and that will work without any problem.

Comment: not able to achieve -@GuruprasadRao

Answer (score 0):

I guess one thing you can do is - write html code for modal and open it as pop up, and in the modal html code add `iframe` tag  with different application URL.
this will work in your case

try this for - https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/PbnBdN for pop up and change modelContent.html with iFrame